# Android RadioGroup onCheckedChanged is called again and again when refreshing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement a setup assistant for my app which is shown when the user starts the app for the first time. I use a PageViewer for this which seems to work fine.

The first page asks the user for the default language. I want to refresh the page when the user selects its language from the RadioGroup. So I need a way to reload the fragment in the chosen language.

```
public class SetupAssistantLanguageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_language_fragment, container, false);

        ((RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.setup_language_radiogroup)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                String langcode = "";
                if (i == R.id.setup_fragment1_languagechooser_en) {
                    langcode = "en";
                } else {
                    langcode = "de";
                }

                ((SetupAssistantActivity) getActivity()).changeLanguage(langcode);
                SetupAssistantLanguageFragment.this.refreshView();
                System.out.println("test1");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void refreshView() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
        System.out.println("test2");
    }
}
```

Changing the language works but only for the pages that follow the first page. This is because the fragment needs to be reloaded when the language changed. I try to reload in refreshView().

The problem is: As soon as I press one radio button, I get an endless loop printing "test1" and "test2". Why is this method called again and again?

How can I reload the fragment exactly one time?

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

In my fragment I first save the current language.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    currentDisplayLang = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
}
```

In onCreateView I only refresh the fragment when the language really changed.

```
((RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.lecture_translator_setup_language_radiogroup)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        String chosenLangcode = i == R.id.setup_fragment1_languagechooser_en ? "en" : "de";

        if (!chosenLangcode.equals(currentDisplayLang)) {
            currentDisplayLang = chosenLangcode.toString();
            ((SetupAssistantActivity) getActivity()).changeLanguage(chosenLangcode);
            SetupAssistantLanguageFragment.this.refreshView();
        }
    }
});
```

Is this the recommended way?